# Ack.vim "No such file or directory" error on windows

Tags: windows, vim, cmd, ack

I had Ack setup and working fine with Vim on my windows XP machine not long ago. Not sure what I did recently, but now it doesn't work.

Here is an example of my problem in Vim:

```
:Ack searchterm
```

Returns this error message:

```
ack: searchterm: No such file or directory
```

If I try to run the command 'manually' in Vim:

```
:!ack searchterm
```

Which opens a cmd.exe dialog with the following message in it:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c ack searchterm
ack: searchterm: No such file or directory
shell returned 1
Hit any key to close this window....
```

Still no luck.

What is weird, is if I go to `START > Run` and then type this command:

```
cmd.exe /c ack searchterm
```

It works fine, and Ack happily searches away for `searchterm`

I don't get it. How can the way Vim calls cmd.exe be any different to how I am calling it via `run` - the result should be the same I would have thought.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**:

I now know the message "No such file or directory" is because Ack thinks I am running this format of the ack command:

```
ack searchterm filename
```

Where filename is the file you want to search in. The problem is that I'm not providing a filename - so I'm not sure why it thinks my searchterm is actually the file to search in.

Somehow vim is passing the arguments incorrectly to cmd.exe - but I just can't see how it could do that

**UPDATE 2**

Vim is not the problem. It must be my version of Ack is buggered somehow.

If I open up cmd.exe and type this:

```
ack searchterm
```

then I also get the error message:

```
ack: searchterm: No such file or directory
```

If I just type ack:

```
ack
```

then it starts searching... for something... who knows what

That is not what I would expect in both examples.  I must be getting closer though...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, I worked it out. My .ackrc file was borked. Apparently this is invalid syntax:

```
--type-set
coffeescript=.eco,.coffee
plsql=.tab,.bdy,.spc,.seq,.tps,.trg,.prc,.vw,.fnc,.syn
```

The correct syntax is:

```
--type-set
coffeescript=.eco,.coffee
--type-set
plsql=.tab,.bdy,.spc,.seq,.tps,.trg,.prc,.vw,.fnc,.syn
```

Why the heck that would cause the error I don't know. But that was the culprit.

Answer (score 1):

Nice work. I was getting the same error from ack using linux (crunchbang).
Turned out I had copied my ~/.ackrc file over from Windows.
Fixed it with good old dos2unix.

```
$ ack -f --python
: No such file or directory
```